# Ionic get Active Page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using Ionic 3 and want to get the name of the active page in order to identify which page I am on in an event subscription.

When I am on a page, the following works:

```
this.nav.getActive().name
```

However, if my root is tabs and I want to identify the page loaded in a tab, the above code just returns the tab page name and not the active page.

**Question**

How do I get the active page name or identifier if it is loaded in a tab?

Comment: Note that ```this.nav.getActive().name``` won't work as expected in --prod mode. (you will get only a minified name)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the component of the page.

Like this `this.nav.getActive().component`

In the tabs page get your tabs element in ViewChild like this:

```
@ViewChild('myTabs') tabRef: Tabs;
```

After that attempt to get selected tab:

```
this.nav.getActive().component.tabRef.getSelected().root
```

This will give you the page

Comment: Thanks.  If within the tab, I navigate to another page, will it show the second page?

Comment: No, my answer is flawed it seems

Comment: Thanks anyway.  I am testing it now just in case though.

Comment: Yes, it only shows the tabs root page, and not the active page.

Comment: Not 100% sure on this but try this.nav.getActive().component.tabRef.viewCtrl.component

Comment: I find that `this.nav.getActive().component.tabRef` is undefined. Perhaps I am doing something wrong

Comment: `this.nav.getActive().component` shows the tabs and their root pages

Comment: You need to go to the html and add #myTabs on the element

Answer (score 1):

In Ionic 3.9.2 you can get even the instance of the current Page with

```
this.viewController.instance
```

This lets you access to all the Page class/member methods with a simple cast.

```
<YuorPageClass>this.viewController.instance.yourMethod()
```

The [official documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/ViewController/) is incomplete, or outdated at the moment.